# Correctly casting info.plist entries to NS* types

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, plist, info.plist

I want to write a helper class to get values from my info.plist and have them be cast to their correct type. So, if I try to access a property that's actually a number as a date, I should get back nil or an error.

I'm having trouble coming up with a nice way to check the type. I've tried to read `[val class]`. In the example below, it comes back as `__NSTaggedDate` for date values, which seems like an implementation detail I don't want to rely on.

```
    - (NSDate *)dateConfig:(NSString *)name
    {
        _configs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"myConfigDictionary"];
        id val = [_configs objectForKey:name];

        // TODO how do I tell?
        if([val class] != ???)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        return val;
    }
```

I want to do this reliably for all other plist types as well. What's an elegant way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the message `isKindOfClass:`

```
if([val isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
{
    return (NSNumber *)val;
}
else
{
    return nil;
}
```

Be aware that there is also `isMemberOfClass:` but you rarely would want this. Many foundation objects are really Core Foundation based (i.e. NSString is NSCFString most of the time).

Comment: Thanks! Being new to objective-c this is a nifty feature I didn't know about.